# RTSP client in Java - link doesn't work

Tags: java, vlcj, rtsp-client

I am writing simple rtsp client. I wanna play video from my IP camera.

I can see preview of my camera when I open this link in VLC.

```
rtsp://@192.168.1.10:554/user=admin_password=tlJwpbo6_channel=1_stream=0.sdp?real_stream
```

But I can't open this link in java. I have only black screen. Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.mrl.RtspMrl;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

public class Main {

    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main(args);
            }
        });
    }

    private Main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("vlcj Tutorial");

        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

        frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);

        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        String address ="C:\\Users\\TheKing\\Desktop\\onviff\\src\\example.mp4";
        address = new RtspMrl().host("@192.168.1.10").port(554).path("/user=admin_password=tlJwpbo6_channel=1_stream=0.sdp?real_stream").value();
        System.out.println(address);
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(address);
    }
}
```

My player works because I tested it with simple mp4 file.

How should I open my rtsp stream ?

Answer (score 0):

After 10 hours of research I found solution for that... Code is Okey here, but there is another mix-up.

This configuration works for me

1. downgrade VLC to [VLC 2.1.2](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.1.2/win64/vlc-2.1.2-win64.exe)
2. install library **uk.co.caprica:vlcj:3.9.0**
3. install library **ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3**
4. install library **ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3**
5. use JDK 1.8.0_60 - 64 bits